# IOS: save a csv o txt file when I delete an app

Tags: ios, xcode, backup, text-files

I'm creating an app and when a person use this app, lot informations are recorded in a txt file; 
If I want to make changes at this app, I must delete app from device. Then, how can I save the txt file before I delete the application?
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the app to make changes, install an updated app with the old app in place to preverve the content of the Documents folder (`NSDocumentDirectory`).

You could also save the data in the cloud whenever the app exits.

Comment: save the data in the cloud? Can you explain this?

Comment: Instead of storing your data in the application that gets deleted, save any data outside the application e.g. somewhere on the internet/cloud/sprawl.